# Project Euler #10 - summation of primes

Tags: python, programming-challenge, primes

[(From Project Euler)](http://projecteuler.net/problem=10)

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
>
> Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

Can someone please help me improve this code?

```
import math

def main():
    lim = 2000000
    i = 2
    now = []
    total = 0
    for i in range(2,lim+1):
        for x in range(1,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
            if len(now) ==2:
                break
            elif i % x == 0:
                now.append(x)

        if len(now) == 1:
            total += i
            print(total)
        now = []
    print(total)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

Comment: You're running through the same numbers every time you evaluate a new `i`. Perhaps a method that only loops once can be implemented *wink wink*

Comment: @OMGtechy Thank you I will take a good look at it :)

Comment: @Calpratt hmm... I'm not sure exactly what you mean :(

Comment: You should read up on prime sieving methods. There are several questions on this site that solve exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Nobody Thank you ill take a look at it :)

Answer (score 8):

**First step : functions and tests**

The very first thing you probably should write is a function computing what you really want : a sum of primes. Also, a value is provided as part of the problem, use this to write a test : as soon as something goes bad, you might notice it.

```
def sum_primes_to_limit(lim):
    i = 2
    now = []
    total = 0
    for i in range(2,lim+1):
        for x in range(1,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
            if len(now) ==2:
                break
            elif i % x == 0:
                now.append(x)

        if len(now) == 1:
            total += i
        now = []
    return(total)

def main():
    assert sum_primes_to_limit(10) == 17
    print(sum_primes_to_limit(2000000))
```

**Making things simpler**

Declaring the `i` variable is not needed.
Similarly, the `now` variable does not need to be defined before the loop and cleared at the end of each iteration : just define it as empty at each iteration.

```
def sum_primes_to_limit(lim):
    total = 0
    for i in range(2,lim+1):
        now = []
        for x in range(1,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
            if len(now) == 2:
                break
            elif i % x == 0:
                now.append(x)

        if len(now) == 1:
            total += i
    return(total)
```

**Making things even simpler**

You don't really care about the content of `now`, just its length. Also, there's no need to check that it does not get longer that 2 at each iteration : just check when you update the list.

Also, you can get rid of the list and make it a simple counter :

```
def sum_primes_to_limit(lim):
    total = 0
    for i in range(2,lim+1):
        nb_div = 0
        for x in range(1,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
            if i % x == 0:
                nb_div += 1
                if nb_div == 2:
                    break

        if nb_div == 1:
            total += i
    return(total)
```

**More function**

Given the way you check if a number is prime or not, it probably make sense to define a function for this :

```
def is_prime(i):
    nb_div = 0
    for x in range(1,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
        if i % x == 0:
            nb_div += 1
            if nb_div == 2:
                return False
    return nb_div == 1

def sum_primes_to_limit(lim):
    total = 0
    for i in range(2,lim+1):
        if is_prime(i):
            total += i
    return(total)
```

**A bit of Python cool syntax**

Among the cool things in Python are generator expressions. Using generator expressions and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), you can write `sum_primes_to_limit` in a concise and fancy way :

```
def sum_primes_to_limit(lim):
    return sum(i for i in range(2,lim+1) if is_prime(i))
```

**Rewriting the function**

You can avoid considering `1` as a divisor if you simply start at 2 (then, you might need some special processing for `1` but I'll leave this to you).

Then your function becomes :

```
def is_prime(i):
    nb_div = 0
    for x in range(2,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
        if i % x == 0:
            nb_div += 1
            if nb_div == 1:
                return False
    return nb_div == 0
```

Then, you don't need the number anymore :

```
def is_prime(i):
    for x in range(2,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
        if i % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

And this looks like it really wants to be written with generator expression (and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) this time).

```
def is_prime(i):
    return all(i % x for x in range(2,int(math.sqrt(i))+1))
```

(Please note that I took this chance to remove a `!= 0` as non-zero boolean will evaluate to True).

**This is all pretty cool but we want speed!**

You want to compute/check primes up to a certain limit. Good for you there is an algorithm just for this : the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Here's an implementation :

```
def sieve(lim):
    primes = [True] * (lim+1)
    primes[0] = primes[1] = False
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(lim))+1):
        if primes[i]:
            for j in range(i*i, lim+1, i):
                primes[j] = False
    return primes

def sum_primes_to_limit(lim):
    primes = sieve(lim)
    return sum(i for i in range(2,lim+1) if primes[i])
```

**Final details**

I am used to Python 3 but if you are using Python 2, `range` generates an actual list. When this is not required (and in your case, this is not required), you should be using `xrange`.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much! I really appreciate it! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU